# How to move rotation point of element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, rotation, easeljs

If i rotate image in EaselJS it rotates around 0,0 point
how do i move it?
Ty! Ras

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **translate(x,y)** where x and y are the new rotation center you want.

Note: If you need to keep operating further, remember to un-translate it (translate again with same but negative values) after you are done with rotation, for this you will need to take into account how much you rotated it.

Answer (score 5):

Subclasses of DisplayObject (Bitmap, Text, Shape, etc.) support regX and regY properties, which let you change the registration point of the object from the default:

- http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html#property_scaleX
- http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html#property_scaleY

I've found this helpful not just for rotation, but other effects as well, such as controlling how a Bitmap flips when setting a negative scaleX/Y.

Best,
Chris

Comment: Yes you're right, that's the best way to do it. I have just posted [THIS QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794748/resize-a-draggable-fill-with-easeljs) If I set the registration point of a simple shape, then it's x and y properties are altered and the shape it's moved. Can you please help me? =)