# Resize a draggable fill with EaselJS

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, resize, easeljs

I've got a project where I'm using EaselJS to create a fill (rectangle) and text over it inside a container. My objective is to make this rectangle and text draggable to move it over the canvas. This is already done and working well.

My problem is when I try to resize the rectangle using `scaleX` and `scaleY` using a onMouseOver handler. This is indeed done, BUT the rectangle just moves away from it's initial point to some other location.

I've read I need to use the `regX` and `regY` properties to override this, but in the context of my code I just can't. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my Javascript code:

```
(function(){
    var stage, myCanvas;
    var update = true;
 
    this.init = function() {
        myCanvas = document.getElementById("stageCanvas");
        stage = new createjs.Stage(myCanvas);
        stage.enableMouseOver();
        stage.mouseEnabled = true;
        stage.mouseMoveOutside = true;
        
        // Reference Shape
        var rectFijo0 = new createjs.Shape();
        rectFijo0.graphics.beginFill("#DCD8D4").rect(140,160,78,35);
        stage.addChild(rectFijo0);
        
        // Shape
        var rectOpt0 = new createjs.Shape();
        rectOpt0.graphics.beginFill("#C51A76").rect(140,160,78,35);
        
        txtOpt0 = new createjs.Text("TEST","bold 20px","#FFF");
        txtOpt0.textAlign ="center";
        txtOpt0.x = 50;
        txtOpt0.y = 50;
        
        // Container
        var containerOpt0= new createjs.Container();
        containerOpt0.mouseEnabled = true;
        //#######
        // Probably here is my problem. I don't understand why if I use regX and regY the rectangle moves the lower right corner to the center, instead of just using this point as a registration point. Why? What I am not understanding?
        //containerOpt0.regX = 78/2;
        //containerOpt0.regY = 35/2;
        //#######
        containerOpt0.onPress = pressHandler;
        containerOpt0.onMouseOver = mouseOverHandler;
        containerOpt0.addChild(rectOpt0, txtOpt0);
        
        stage.addChild(containerOpt0);
        stage.update();
        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);
    }
    
    function pressHandler(e){
    // onPress Handler to drag
        var offset = {x:e.target.x-e.stageX, y:e.target.y-e.stageY};
        e.onMouseMove = function(ev) {
            e.target.x = ev.stageX+offset.x;
            e.target.y = ev.stageY+offset.y;
            update = true;
        }
    }
    
    function mouseOverHandler(e){
        e.target.scaleX = .5;
        e.target.scaleY = .5;
        update = true;
    }
    
    function tick() {
    if (update) {
            update = false;
            stage.update();
        }
    }

    window.onload = init();
}());
```

Here's my [JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/metafaniel/WfMGr/) so you can see exactly what's going on. Just drag the mouse over the rectangle to see what I mean. It must be something easy to achieve but I'm not certain how.

Comment: I appreciate this is an old question, but while it does not have a [mcve] in the body, it may be subject to closure. Could you bring the essence of the code into the question itself? There's nothing wrong with JS Fiddle links, but ideally questions are self-contained as well.

Comment: @halfer Fair enough. At present, I have this more in mind that back then. I've added my Javascript code into the question to clarify the context within StackOverflow.

Comment: Great, thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You issue is, that you are drawing your rects not at 0|0, the "standard" way is to draw your shape starting at 0|0 and then position the shape itself somewhere through `.x` and `.y`

```
rectOpt0.graphics.beginFill("#C51A76").rect(140,160,78,35);
=> changed to
rectOpt0.graphics.beginFill("#C51A76").rect(0,0,78,35);
```

and additionally I then placed the container at 140|160 + the regX/Y offset:

```
containerOpt0.regX = 78/2; //regX/Y to have is scale to the center point
containerOpt0.regY = 35/2;
containerOpt0.x = 140 + 78/2;  //placement + regX offset/correction
containerOpt0.y = 160 + 35/2;
```

here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WfMGr/2/

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, now I understand what I was doing wrong. Thanks a lot ;)